# How to use Input taken from the user using Input Box to replace it in the VBA

Tags: vba

Hi I'm writing a VBA to create few folders in the user defined path and naming it as per user.

Folder structure as follows
Folder 1>>>Rev #

First: I need to take the path from user where he wants to create a folder
Second:  I need user to specify name for the folder, folder should be created on the same name
Third: I need user to mention the Rev # of the folder which need to be reflected in subfolder name (Rev #)

Have written the following code for the same.
Kindly have a look and lemme know how to get the above output

```
Sub Create_Folder()
'
' Create_Folder Macro
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String

'
a = InputBox("Enter File Path", "FILE PATH")
b = InputBox("Enter File Name", "FILE NAME")
c = InputBox("Enter Rev #", "REV NUMBER")

Dim OriginalText As String
Dim CorrectedText As String
OriginaText = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Macro"
CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Macro", "a")

OriginaText = "Folder1"
CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "Folder 1", "b")

OriginaText = "Rev #"
CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "Rev #", "c")

MkDir ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Macro\Folder 1")
MkDir ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Macro\Folder 1\Rev #")`    
End sub
```

Comment: I think you're going at this the wrong way. For example, you can use [`Application.GetSaveAsFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) or other more "standardized" folder/fiile pickers.

Answer (score 0):

test this out.

```
Dim UserName as string, DefaultLoc as string, Destination as string, FileName as string

DefaultLoc = "C:\Users\"
Destination = InputBox("Enter File Path", "FILE PATH")
FileName = InputBox("Enter File Name", "FILE NAME")
UserName = Application.UserName 'note this may not be the type of username you are looking for as I believe this is the Office 365 username.

Location = DefaultLoc & UserName & "\Desktop\Macro\" & Destination & FileName
 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Location
```

I believe this should work, the idea is to collect all the data you need for the saveas function which I believe takes the entire path, though I do not know if it creates the location if it does not exist already, you may need a line of code to create the folder structure above it before you try and save it. Hope it works.

Comment: Hi Scott
Thanks for your help..
When i try the above code m getting an error msg

Comment: Scott, Thanks for your help.
When i try the above code m getting an error msg
"The file could not be accessed, try on of the following:
Make sure the specified folder exists" etc
Let me clearly explain what i need
I need to take path from user, this path will be in server, so there is no question of user name here.
User has to specify the file name too based on which the folder will be created in the path (in server) specified by user
Finally  there should be a sub folder under main folder with name Rev # (user has to specify the #) which will be reflected once the subfolder is created.

Comment: more then likely the code is pulling a the office 365 username. 
instead of 
Location = DefaultLoc & UserName & "\Desktop\Macro\" & Destination & FileName

try Location = DefaultLoc & "username" & "\Desktop\Macro\" & Destination & FileName

where the "username" is the actual username of a user you know exists on the server